# Use Custom Delegate in AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, appdelegate

i'm trying to add a Custom Delegate in App Delegate, and i'm doing it in this way:

```
AppDelegate.h

@protocol AppDelegateDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)finishSync:(BOOL)success;

@end

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <AppDelegateDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Then i'm trying to use this delegate in other view connected in UITabViewController, and i do it in this way:

```
FirstView.h

#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface FirstView : UIViewController <AppDelegateDelegate>

@end

FirstView.m

@implementation FirstView

...

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  AppDelegate *appController = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  appController.customDelegate = self;

}
```

the FirstView works perfectly, but for example if i switch in SecondViewController that have the same code to implement the delegate, the delegate don't works anymore neither in the FirstView...what i wrong?

**EDIT:**

i have tried the rdelmar answer, but don't work, now i'm explain better my situation, i have 4 view in a UITabBarController, this view are loaded in the didfinishloading method in app delegate, then the app open in the first view, and this is the log in view ViewDidAppear like you do in your answer:

```
<FirstView: 0xae10280>
```

then i switch in the second view and this is the viewdidappear nslog of the deleagate:

```
<SecondView: 0x9f79b10>
```

then i switch in the thirdView and this is the nslog:

```
<ThirdView: 0xba86200>
```

and the last is the FourthView:

```
<FourtView: 0xba875b0>
```

so seems that all the delegate works in all view, then i have tried to switch to the first view, and this is the log:

```
(null)
```

i switch the third view:

```
(null)
```

the second:

```
(null)
```

the fourth:

```
(null)
```

no work anymore,so i stop the application and i have run it again, and start with the firstView:

```
<FirstView: 0xad28730>
```

switch to second view:

```
<SecondView: 0x9f682e0>
```

return in the firstView:

```
(null)
```

switch to second view:

```
(null)
```

switch to third view:

```
<ThirdView: 0xab297e0>
```

switch to fourthView:

```
<FourthView: 0xab28430>
```

then again to the third view:

```
(null)
```

so as you can see the problem it's that the first time works, then when return on a view the delegate is null, any idea?

**EDIT 2:**

i have notice also that if i switch view between the NavigationController the delegate is never (null), instead switching view in UITabBarController as i do i my code give null...so it's a problem of UITabBarController views i think...

Answer (score 1):

An object can only have one delegate at a time. Try setting the delegate to nil in the viewWillDisappear method of FirstView, and see if that helps.

This worked for me. I moved the setting of the delegate to the viewWillAppear in the first controller, so it would reset if I go back to it from the second. My controllers are in a navigation controller, and I'm using pushes and pops to go back and forth. Both controllers have this same code (except for the logs):

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) AppDelegate *appController;
@end

@implementation ViewController //This is the first controller


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.appController = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.appController.customDelegate = self;
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"First says: %@",self.appController.customDelegate);
}


-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"First viewWillDisappear");
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.appController.customDelegate = nil;
}

- (void)finishSync:(BOOL)success {

}
```

Comment: what you mean with an object can only have one delegate at a time? that the FirstView can have only one delegate or AppDelegate can have only one delegate at a time?

Comment: AppDelegate.  AppDelegate is the one that HAS the delegate, not FirstView (FirstView IS the delegate).

Comment: ok thanks, but for write delegate = nil in view will disappear i have to declare appController in the Header file .h right? or i can do in this way: AppDelegate *appController = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  appController.customDelegate = nil; in view will disappear? what is the best?

Comment: @Piero, you've already done it the second way to set the delegate, so do it the same way to set it to nil (or better yet, make appController a property, and then you can reuse it in the viewWillDisappear method).

Comment: don't works, maybe i have to add the delegate in the viewwillappear and not in the view did load what you think?

Comment: Did it work in viewDidLoad for FirstView? I'm assuming it did, since that's where you put it. So, I don't know why it shouldn't work for SecondView, but go ahead and try it in viewWillAppear and see what happens.

Comment: no dont' works, i have tried to insert it in viewwillappear and set it nil in viewwilldisappear, and sometime works and sometime don't works, i can't understand why...

Comment: You should really be calling super prior to the rest of your code.

Comment: @MarkM, I don't think it matters when you call it. From the Apple docs: "If you override this method, you must call super at some point in your implementation."

Comment: It definitely matters when you call it. It's a good habit to get into. 2 reasons:

You might depend on that initialization. 
You might want to override super view controller's initialization

Comment: @Piero, it appears that the timing of when things appear and disappear is a little different in a tab bar controller. It worked for me, putting the setting of the delegate in viewDidAppear, and the nil'ing in the viewWillDisappear. I've edited my answer to show that.

Comment: @rdelmar thank you very much! now works! can i insert in the viewdidappear also for the navigationcontroller or presentmodalview? to do the same thing in all the code? or in the other view i use viewwillappear? thanks again for the help! :)

Comment: @Piero, the navigation controller just presents other controllers' views, so it should never need to be the delegate. As for the presentViewController method, try it in both places, and see what works.

Comment: I have explained myself badly, I meant that I want to use customdelegate of appdelegate you as you did in a view held by a navigationController and I wanted to know if put it in viewwillappear or viedidappear...:)